# ActiveRecord exists? caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to figure out what are the rules for `ActiveRecord` per-request SQL cache. The documentation doesn't seem to list the details.

When I run the following in the Rails console:

```
2.times { User.where(id: 1).first }
```

I get a `User Load` and a `CACHE` log. But when I try to do:

```
2.times { User.where(id: 1).exists? }
```

I get two queries without caching, even though they use the same `SELECT` query text twice. Is there something I can do to allow caching it in AR, or is it just not supported?

Comment: AFAIK, rails caches the `SELECT` query happening more than once in the same action call. However, the cache is invalidated if it observes the mutation on table which could change the result.

Comment: And as for no `CACHE` in `exists`, it seems to be a bug with mysql and postgres adapter in rails. It was fixed in rails 5.1.5 - https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29454